# When using subdivision modifier on my car model,faint lines appear which I believe are unaligned rows of vertices

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have tried to align the rows of vertices manually but to no avail.I have also put a wireframe image if you need one

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe show a screenshot or even share your file (just the part with the problem): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: We can't tell where the problem is just from the wireframe. Add another image showing the actual problem.

Comment: I want make the faint lines in the windscreen and near the left tyre  dissapear

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gwrVYkAx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gwrVYkAx/)